# Find all pairs of elements within an array that sum up to a given value

Tags: python, algorithm, debugging

I am stuck in one of **Hackerrank** problems with following problem description :-

You will be given an array of integers and a target value. Determine the number of pairs of array elements that have a difference equal to a target value.

For example, given an array of `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and a target value of `1`, we have three values meeting the condition: `(2,1), (3,2), (4,3)`. So function pairs should return value `3`.

**We have to implement pairs function with following parameters :-**

```
k: an integer, the target difference
arr: an array of integers
```

**Constraints :-**

```
1> Each Integer in arr[i] will be unique and positive.
2> target k will also be positive.
```

My below function implementation is failing one of 18 test cases because of the wrong result. Can anyone please help me debug the issue :-

```
def binSearch(target,arr):
    lower = 0
    upper = len(arr)-1
    while lower <= upper:
        mid = int((lower + upper)/2)
        if(arr[mid] == target):
            return 1
        elif(arr[mid] > target):
            upper = mid - 1
        elif(arr[mid] < target):
            lower = mid + 1
    return -1

def pairs(k, arr):
    arr.sort()
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        target = abs(arr[i] - k)
        if(arr[i] == target):
            pass
        elif(binSearch(target,arr) == 1):
            count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: `target = abs(arr[i] - k)` doesn't seem right to me. Let's say `k=7`. If a[i] is 3, then the target should be 10, but `abs(arr[i] - k)` is 4.

Comment: @user3386109 you are absolutely correct. I removed the abs function and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

This should be an O(n) solution (where `n` is the size of `arr`).  First, convert the array to a set.  Then iterate through each value in `arr` and check if `arr + k` is in the set, i.e. the difference between the other value and the current value `val` is equal to `k`.  If so, increment `counter` by one.

```
def pairs(k, arr):
    counter = 0
    set_arr = set(arr)
    for val in arr:
        if val + k in set_arr:
            counter += 1
    return counter
```

Comment: +1 . This is a better solution but my question was to find out the issue with my code which user3386109 did point out.

Answer (score 0):

**By java, for rum time it will take O(n log n) to sort the array, and for binary search it takes O(log m) so O(n log n + log m) == > O(n log n)
space it will take O(n)**

```
public static ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairThatHaveDiffrenceK(int[] arr , int arrLength , int k ){



        ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.sort(arr);

        for (int i = 0; i < arrLength ; i++) {
            temp = arr[i] + k;
            int testIfFound = indexFromBinarySearch(arr, temp);
            if (testIfFound != -1){
                arrayList.add(new Pair<>(arr[i],arr[testIfFound] ));
           }
        }

        return arrayList ;
    }


    public static int indexFromBinarySearch(int[] arr, int valueForTarget){
        int start =0 ;
        int end = arr.length-1;
        while (start <= end){
            int mid = (start+end)/2 ;
            if(arr[mid] == valueForTarget){
                return mid;
            }
            else if(valueForTarget > arr[mid])
                start =mid+1;
            else
                end = mid-1;

        }
        return -1 ;
    }
```